Ncurses c++ printing arrow codes in terminal instead of reading them
I'm in kali linux trying to do a simple cpp program using ncurses but whenever I try to read an arrow key press, the escape code appears on screen. I cannot figure out what might be happening.
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

typedef struct rep_player{
    char simbolo;
    int posX;
    int posY;
} * Player;


void escucharEntrada(Player jugador){
    while(true){
        int ch = wgetch(stdscr);
        if(ch == KEY_RIGHT){
            printf("derecha");
        }
    }
}
void imprimirPantalla(Player jugador){

}

int main(){
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();
    const int PANTALLA_LARGO = 6;
    const int PANTALLA_ANCHO = 6;
    const char PANTALLA_FONDO = 'X';
    Player jugador = new rep_player;
    jugador->simbolo = 'O';
    jugador->posX = 0;
    jugador->posY = 0;

    while(true){
        imprimirPantalla(jugador);
        escucharEntrada(jugador);
    }


return 0;
};

When I press arrow keys in the terminal when running the program the codes appear:


Nico: Did you get what you needed from the answer or do you want me to clarify anything?

You need to call initscr():

initscr is normally the first curses routine to call when initializing a program.  A few special routines sometimes need to be called before it; these are slk_init(3X), filter, ripoffline, use_env.  For
multiple-terminal applications, newterm may be called before initscr.

int main() {
    initscr();
    //...

You should also not be using traditional output functions, like printf, in your curses programs. Use the curses functions:
void escucharEntrada(Player jugador) {
    while(true) {
        int ch = wgetch(stdscr);
        if(ch == KEY_RIGHT) {
            printw("derecha");           // not printf
        }
    }
}

Sidenotes: Your use of new is rather pointless here and the program leaks memory. You also don't need to typedef your structs in C++.
